Canon IR_ADV 4025i Printer Issue
I have here Canon IRA 4025i copier and its sending function not working. While sending to e-mail it keeps resending and finaly ends with error #995
Any suggestions.
network is working fine and all settings should be
also sending to ftp server works.
Solution and the cause for that error.
